# Filter datatable by multiple statements

Tags: c#, linq

I have a datatable called `Designs`

I filter this table depending of list of values I received from user

```
List<Guid> values = new List<Guid>();

foreach (var checkbox in cbo)
{
    //logic to fill list...
}
```

Once I do that I filter my datatabe with LINQ as:

```
designs = Designs.AsEnumerable()
       .Where(row => values.Contains(row.Field<Guid>("DesignGroupId"))).CopyToDataTable();
```

And it works pretty good. But now I want to add one condition to my query. I want to get columns who have field `"DesignKey" = null`. So I try:

```
designs = Designs.AsEnumerable()
       .Where(row => values.Contains(row.Field<Guid>("DesignGroupId")) && row.Field<int>("DesignKey") == null).CopyToDataTable();
```

But I get an exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The source contains no DataRows.'

What am I doing wrong? Regards

Comment: Do you have data that match both conditions?

Comment: Yes I have data... my second condition just add another row @Sach

Comment: @Beto since your new condition is added with a && operator, there is no way this new condition would add a row. This will only return the rows that match both conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing would be to know which method throws the exception.

In your case, the CopyToDatabase method will throw this exception, as stated [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatableextensions.copytodatatable?view=netframework-4.8) :

> InvalidOperationException
>
> The source sequence does not contain any DataRow objects.

To make sure, you can split your request :

```
var designEnum= Designs.AsEnumerable();
var firstSelect = designEnum.Where(row => values.Contains(row.Field<Guid>("DesignGroupId"));
var secondSelect = firstSelect.Where(row => row.Field<int>("DesignKey") == null);
if (secondSelect.Count == 0)
{
    //Handle the fact that you have no data
    design = null;
}
else
{
    designs = secondSelect.CopyToDataTable();
}
```

And this is much easier to debug as you can go line by line with the debugger. You can compact the code later on.

Answer (score 0):

you cant CopyToDataTable null

this will work for you:

```
void Main()
{

    DataTable Designs = new DataTable();
    Designs.Columns.Add("DesignGroupId", typeof(Guid));
    Designs.Rows.Add(Guid.NewGuid());
    Designs.Rows.Add(Guid.NewGuid());
    Designs.Rows.Add(Guid.NewGuid());
    Designs.Rows.Add(Guid.Parse("7c176832-593c-402f-9def-fbe12da3742f"));

    List<Guid> values = new List<Guid>();
    values.Add(Guid.NewGuid());
    values.Add(Guid.NewGuid());
    values.Add(Guid.NewGuid());
    //values.Add(Guid.Parse("7c176832-593c-402f-9def-fbe12da3742f"));

    var res = Designs.AsEnumerable().Where(row => values.Contains(row.Field<Guid>("DesignGroupId"))).ToList();
      if (res.Count > 0 )
        Designs =  res.CopyToDataTable();
      else
        Designs.Clear();
}
```